Overcome the latency/lag of (=importrange) function
We know that importrange function in Google sheet has some latency in refreshing the data continuously and can reaches upto one hour in order to update any changes made on the reference page/sheet. For example, =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1kBgsGhVVT75XRVTt******r0ZjEiHtokXrlGrnm7bU", "DailyOncall!L5:T27"), "")
Whenever a change was made to the spreadsheet ID (1kBgsGhVVT75XRVTt******r0ZjEiHtokXrlGrnm7bU), those changes are not reflected immediately on the receiving sheet that has the function importrange.
Is there a solution to this like using the importrange function within the Apps Script instead? or adding a script to flush/refresh the receiving page at a specific time ? Or using a third party service?
Reloading the page multiple times even if the changes already made on the reference page, doesn't solve the lag/latency.

Put target tab in the same spreadsheet file as the source tab and use an { array expression } instead of importrange() to get immediate response.

In this way, the viewrs can see the whole tabs in the sheet

The aim of creating target sheet with import range is to make it shareable to others without viewing the main data in the reference sheet. I'm looking for a way to force this function to recalculate on demand

importrange() lets editors "peek around" the source spreadsheet so it isn't as secure as one may think. If you are fine with users getting view-only access, you may want to explore Looker Studio. See the Gallery for examples of what you can do with it. See What is the XY problem?
